# Filling previous values within a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want the values to `ffill()` in `S0.0,S1.0,S2.0` within the 'ID' group

```
        ID      Close   S0.0  S1.0  S2.0
0      UNITY    11.66   NaN   54    NaN
1      UNITY    11.55   56    NaN   NaN
2      UNITY    11.59   NaN   NaN   78
3      TRINITY  11.69   47    NaN   NaN
4      TRINITY  11.37   NaN   69    NaN
5      TRINITY  11.89   NaN   NaN   70
```

intended result:

```
       ID      Close   S0.0  S1.0  S2.0
0      UNITY    11.66   NaN   54    NaN
1      UNITY    11.55   56    54    NaN
2      UNITY    11.59   56    54    78
3      TRINITY  11.69   47    NaN   NaN
4      TRINITY  11.37   47    69    NaN
5      TRINITY  11.89   47    69    70
```

Here are my attempts and their undesired outcomes:

Attempt 1:

```
df[df['S0.0']==""] = np.NaN
df[df['S1.0']==""] = np.NaN
df[df['S2.0']==""] = np.NaN

df['S0.0'].groupby('ID').fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
df['S1.0'].groupby('ID').fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
df['S2.0'].groupby('ID').fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
```

output:

```
raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'ID'
```

Attempt 2:

```
 df.groupby('ID')[['S0.0', 'S1.0', 'S2.0']].ffill() 
#this makes no difference to the data.

#but when I try this:
df = df.groupby('ID')[['S0.0', 'S1.0', 'S2.0']].ffill()

df
```

Output:

```
  S0.0  S1.0  S2.0
  NaN   54    NaN
  56    54    NaN
  56    54    78
  47    NaN   NaN
  47    69    NaN
  47    69    70
```

which again is not what I wanted. Little help will be appreciated.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***
The second attempt is the right one! Just don't specify the Sx.0's columns.

```
id = df.ID
df = pd.concat([id,df.groupby('ID').ffill()],axis=1)
```

**output:**

```
    ID      Close      S0.0     S1.0    S2.0
0   UNITY       11.66   NaN     54.0    NaN
1   UNITY       11.55   56.0    54.0    NaN
2   UNITY       11.59   56.0    54.0    78.0
3   TRINITY     11.69   47.0    NaN     NaN
4   TRINITY     11.37   47.0    69.0    NaN
5   TRINITY     11.89   47.0    69.0    70.0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But note that "ID" goes missing. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code. I don't actually know why it goes missing

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df[['S0.0', 'S1.0', 'S2.0']] = df.groupby('ID')[['S0.0', 'S1.0', 'S2.0']].ffill()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Close  S0.0  S1.0  S2.0
0  11.66   NaN  54.0   NaN
1  11.55  56.0  54.0   NaN
2  11.59  56.0  54.0  78.0
3  11.69  47.0   NaN   NaN
4  11.37  47.0  69.0   NaN
5  11.89  47.0  69.0  70.0
```